Google Drive Files API to get ALL files in a folder - even those that are marked as BINARY
I have 3 files in a Shared Drive in a folder - all of these are the same text file/data

Uploaded the first one "abc123" and Drive treats it as a "Binary File"
Made a copy of "abc123" in the same Drive Folder and renamed it to "xyz123.txt" and Drive still treats it as a "Binary File"
On my local system - made a copy of the same file and renamed to "def123.txt" and uploaded it to this folder - notice Drive is treating it as a text file - MIME Type = text/plain

Folder Screenshot
Notice that the icons are different - Binary Files are a darker blue than the Text File
When using the Files API - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files - Here is the simple query
"1B8sn6MYwJdv6pnBYVxMltL7xHv2gwrf8" in parents and trashed = false

Where the ID above is for the Folder
I am expecting to get 3 files back - but only get the file type with a mimeType text/plain returned back
[
  {
      'driveId' => '0ABOnA8vd3emBUk9PVA',
      'id' => '1VmwioaAXtRJgErh6321K5pnvdzt-8dWO',
      'kind' => 'drive#file',
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
      'name' => 'def123.txt',
      'teamDriveId' => '0ABOnF8vd3emBUk9PVA'
   }
 ]

How can the files "abc123" and "xyz123.txt" - which Drive considers both Binary Files - be included in the results by the Google Drive Files API when querying for a list of files??
I have tried to make the query more specific by adding the mimeType for Binary files but this does not seem to work.
"1B8sn6MYwJdv6pnBYVxMltL7xHv2gwrf8" in parents 
and mimeType = "BINARY-MIME-TYPE-HERE" 
and trashed = false

I have tried all of these without success

application/octet-stream
application/octetstream
binary/octet-stream
application/binary
application/x-binary
octet/stream


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. By the way, in the case of Google Drive, even when the extension of the existing file is changed, the mimeType of the file is not changed. Please be careful about this.

Hi - I am using the File query API - shown here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files

Hi - I am using the File query API - shown here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files
The simple query I am using - shown in the main post - is NOT returning the 2 files that Drive considers Binary Files - it only returns the one file that is classified text/plain  -
I want the query to return all 3 files in the folder - no matter the mimeType

I determined that the Binary File mimeType are application/octet-stream
Here is process I followed to get file info
Get the ID of a file - right click and select SHARE then COPY LINK
Paste the link somewhere and get the FILE ID from the URL
Go to this URL
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get
On the right hand side - click "TRY IT" button and authenticate
Copy the File ID
Set both supportsAllDrives and supportsTeamDrives to TRUE
Click the Execute Button
It should return JSON results for the file

{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "13NYLblMOInjJiieCqi0iLG6_QaornaZb",
"name": "abc123",
"mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
"teamDriveId": "0ABOnE8vd6emBUk2PVA",
"driveId": "0ABOnE8vd1emBUk7PVA"
}

Thank you for replying. About I am using the File query API - shown here developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files The simple query I am using - shown in the main post - is NOT returning the 2 files that Drive considers Binary Files - it only returns the one file that is classified text/plain - I want the query to return all 3 files in the folder - no matter the mimeType , can you provide your current search query?

Turns out that the query string passed up was not being escaped properly - once this was done correctly - all of the expected files were returned
"1B8sn3MYwJdv6pnBYVxMltL4xKv2gwrf2" in parents and trashed = false
The correct escaped query string looks like this
%221B8sn3MYwJdv6pnBYVxMltL4xKv2gwrf2%22%20in%20parents%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false
